# Show value from input box by pressing the button

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, react-tsx

Goal:
Show the value of the element id ttt in console when you press the button "showvalue"

Problem:
The code won't work what part of the code am I missing?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-sgczgk?

Info:
Newbie in React TS

Thank you!

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

interface AppProps {}
interface AppState {
  name: string;
}

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  public textInput;

  focusTextInput() {
    console.log(this.textInput.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input id="ttt" type="text" ref={this.textInput} />

        <input type="button" value="showvalue" onClick={this.focusTextInput} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.textInput` is not the `HtmlInputelement` its `RefObject`. If you want to access the underlying element you should be using `this.textInput.current.value`

[Fixed fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-yhtztu?file=index.tsx)

By the way, if you are using typescript you should be annotating your types correctly.

If you annotate your `public textInput;` as  `public textInput : RefObject<HtmlInputElement>;` it would warn you that `value` doesn't exists on type `RefObject<HtmlInputElement>`